# What is the difference between unique index and monotonic index?

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I'm trying to use [pandas.Index.get_loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) to return the index (as an `int`) of the nearest value, but occasionally it returns a `slice` object instead. According to the documentation,

> get_loc returns int if unique index, slice if monotonic index, else mask.

But it doesn't look like the behavior is consistent. For example, with the following index:

```
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2019-12-24 12:04:54',
                        '2019-12-26 20:09:22',
                        '2020-12-27 07:44:35'])
```

Using `idx.get_loc('2019-12-27', method='ffill')` returns `slice(2, 2, None)`, whereas `idx.get_loc('2019-12-29', method='ffill')` returns `2`. Changing the method from `'ffill'` to `'bfill'` doesn't seem to change the result.

My aim is to slice all points from the beginning of the index like `idx[:i]` where `i` is an int returned by `get_loc`. Another solution might to modify the beginning of the `slice` object, if that is possible.

**Edit:**
Apparently, a `slice` is a built-in object with *read-only* data attributes start, stop and step (see docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice)). This means you can check whether the result of `get_loc` is an `int` and if not, use `idx[:slice.stop]` to get all elements up to the desired index.

I'm still interested in the original question though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with basic definitions.

## Unique Index

A **unique index** is an index that contains non-duplicate labels. In such an index there cannot be two or more identical labels.

To check if a given index is unique, one can use `pd.Index.is_unique` attribute, e.g.:

```
>>> pd.Index(['s', 'a', 'm']).is_unique
True
>>> pd.Index(['s', 'a', 'm', 'a']).is_unique
False
```

As the documentation mentions, an example of such an index would be `pd.Index(list('abc'))`, containing three unique labels `a`, `b` and `c`, and which happens to be monotonic as well. A **unique non-monotonic index** could be, for example, `pd.Index(list('acb'))`, which breaks the forward order at the backward move from `c` to `b`.

## Monotonic Index

Monotonicity is a mathematical property that indicates a given function maintains a non-increasing or non-decreasing order throughout its domain. In pandas, a **monotonic index** is an index that follows this property.

Similarly to uniqueness, you can check the monotonicity of an index with an attribute, `pd.Index.is_monotonic` or its derivatives, i.e. `pd.Index.is_monotonic_increasing` and `pd.Index.is_monotonic_decreasing`.

In this case, the documentation presents another example: `pd.Index(list('abbc'))`, which is a non-unique monotonic index with a duplicated label `b`. A non-unique non-monotonic index, `pd.Index(list('abcb'))` is also mentioned. The duplicated label is again `b` while the order is broken at `c -> b`, which is against the previously established order `a -> b -> c`.

---

## pd.Index.get_loc

This pandas Index method uses the aforedefined concepts to determine its return value. Its expected behaviour is specified as follows. If an index is unique, then it is supposed to return an `int` index value. If it is not unique, the method considers the monotonicity of the index. If it happens to be monotonous, it returns a `slice`. Otherwise, it returns a mask.

Your sample index, `idx` is unique (and monotonous, albeit it is irrelevant), therefore you would expect, `get_loc` should return an `int`. However, this is guaranteed only for **exact** label matches. This is not true for partial matches, like the ones you are using. I am leaving you with the output that shows the difference in usage:

```
>>> idx.get_loc('2019-12-24')
slice(0, 1, None)
>>> idx.get_loc('2019-12-24 12:04:54')
0
```